# Batch File for application restart

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm new to this so try to keep my question relevant! I'm trying to write a batch file that will re-start an application on a 2 state condition i.e. when a ping fails and then recovers. I've written something gleaned from information given on this site (see below) that just restarts it when it fails and changes the DOS prompt colour, but it's not ideal. Can anyone point me in the general direction to restart the app on a  down -> up condition with a ping? Many thanks!

```
@echo off
cls
set INTERVAL=120
:top
ping -n 1 -w 2000 192.168.1.10 | find "TTL=" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET OUT=4F & echo Request timed out.) ELSE (SET OUT=2F)
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto reset
COLOR %OUT%
ping -n 2 -l 100 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto top
:reset
timeout %INTERVAL%
taskkill /IM  VmsClientApp.exe /F
Ping -n 1 -l 256 127.0.0.1 >nul
start /D "c:\Program Files\Avigilon\Avigilon Control Center Client\" VmsClientApp.exe
echo The Client is now loading...
goto top
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "interval=120"
    cls

:up
    color 2f
    set "down="

:test
    ping -n 1 -w 2000 192.168.1.10 | find "TTL=" 
    if not errorlevel 1 if defined down goto :restart
    if     errorlevel 1 set "down=1" & color 4f
    timeout %interval%
    goto :test

:restart
    taskkill /IM  VmsClientApp.exe /F
    start "" /D "c:\Program Files\Avigilon\Avigilon Control Center Client" VmsClientApp.exe
    goto :up
```